# Excel byte[] (OLE) to xls c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, hssfworkbook

I'm trying to parse a .xls document that is saved in a SQL database using VB for Access. It's saved as an OLE document.

What I do is write the document using a binary writer

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs, document.GetTextEncoding());
bw.Write(document);
bw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

So, the file is saved but when I open it on Office365 it gives me a grey page:
[image]

But, Windows explorer preview shows the document!!!!

[image]

I've tryed to open file and save with Microsoft Interop but I got the same results. I've tryed to copy to a new file with HSSFWorkbook but the same ocurrs. With .doc, .jpg , .pdf I first try to allocate the header in the file to get the start position for the binary writer but I cannot figure out if .xls has this kind of header. (Most of those .pdf, .doc, .jpg document can be opened)

This is Interop code:

```
 excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, Notify: false, CorruptLoad: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile).
                           SaveAs(filePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel5, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Have tryed changing the XLFileFormat, even sometimes I can't preview it.

HSSF code:

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
          hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
          file.Close();
   }

 FileStream file2 = new FileStream(filePath+ "_mod", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

           hssfwb.Write(file2);
           file2.Close();
```

Happens the same, can preview but can't open.

**EDIT**

document:

```
byte[] doc = (byte[])reader["DEX_Documento"];
```

It's read from database, it's a hex string parsed to byte. Unfortunately, is hard to find a document that I can give you the string due to legal terms.

Also, I can read the rows with the HSSF solution, but the problem persists.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including how `document` is declared and populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a library without using Office that works.

```
Spire.Xls.Workbook wbFromStream = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
wbFromStream.LoadFromStream(file);
wbFromStream.SaveToFile(filePath+".xls", Spire.Xls.ExcelVersion.Version2013);
file.Close();
```